# C++: Asterisks, Ampersand and Star?

Tags: c++, operators

Recently I came across this video on [Programming Paradigms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTSvthW34GU) and the prof. used terms like Asterisks, Star, and Ampersand.

This was what how he used those operators:

```
int i = 37;
float f = *(float*)&i;
```

And how he voiced line 2 while writing it:

> Float "f" equals asterisk float star, ampersand of i

I understand what asterisk and ampersand mean, but what is the significance of using star here? Is it synonymous to asterisk?

Comment: He forgot to mention the parentheses.

Comment: Makes me wonder, if you say anything at all, why not simply say what it does instead...

Comment: "Equals" is `==`. `=` is "assignment". I wonder how often this guy writes C++ code...

Comment: if he had read it out as "float f flibble doobry float wobble blurb i" it would still have meant the same thing in code.  Don't get too hung up on the names of symbols, because people will always use different terms for them (Especially those people whose native language is something other than English).   It's more important to understand how the compiler interprets those symbols depending on the context in which they're used.

Comment: The professor probably said the literal meaning of the symbol instead of "assignment operator" for brevity sake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `*` after the `float` is used to form a type. Very often when referring to a pointer type in words people will say "star" after the type rather "pointer", eg. "malloc returns a void star". I've never heard anyone use "asterisk" to refer to a type.

The `*` at the start is used to de-reference the pointer thereby accessing the value it points to (interpreted as a `float` due to the following cast). Again, in my own experience I've never heard anyone use "asterisk" here. People just tend to say "de-reference" to describe the operation being performed.

I wouldn't read too much into it. There are two different contexts here as you rightly spotted and as long as you understand what they mean from a C++ point of view then that's fine.

Comment: Thanks! This effectively answers why the prof said "star" instead of "asterisk".

Answer (score 3):

```
float f = *(float*)&i;
```

In this case left * and right * has different sematics. Left * means value getting by refernce. Right * declares reference type.

Comment: " has different semantics" Unreleated to pronunciation - it is still the same symbol.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it synonymous to asterisk?

Yes. Shift+8 on **MY** windows keyboard. Your example demonstrates why you shouldn't try to read C++ program aloud symbol by symbol. "Equals" in C++ is "==". "=" is assignment. Plus he forgot to tell about parentheses and semicolon. At this point (4 mistakes in single line of code) he could've written the damn thing silently.

It would have been much better if the dude read this part:

```
float f = *(float*)&i;
```

somewhat like this:

*"Take pointer to i, C-style cast it into pointer to float, dereference, and assign value to float variable f"*. Makes much more sense that "star/asterisk" gibberish.

P.S. If you really love tongue twisters, you could try reading aloud any code that uses boost, iostreams, operator <<, casts, bitwise operations and "camel case" to distinguish between classes and methods. Such exercise will not improve your programming skills, of course...

Comment: SHift+8 is "(" on my keyboard (windows, too!). You should not assume all keyboards have the same layout all over the world

Comment: -1: The OP knows it is the same symbol. I think that's very rude. The question is simply asking if there was a significance to the use of the two different terms based on the two different contexts in which * was used.

Comment: @Troubadour: "I think that's very rude" I don't think it is very rude, and it wasn't intended to be rude. So if *you* think it is rude it is because you're jumping to conclusions. " significance to the use of the two different terms" No there wasn't any significance. As far as I know "star" and "asterisk" are not part of some well-known C++ jargon and do not commonly refer to "derefernece" or "cast". To distinguish it would make sense to use better terms - "derefernece" and "cast".

Answer (score 0):

I think the presenter just wanted to avoid an awkward silence while he wrote out the code. As far as I know, there is no difference between asterisk and star in this context.

Answer (score 0):

& parameter = print address

& type = ref() :  that means I want this guy's new name not duplicate.

* parameter = get value from this address

* type = store address  (pointer variable)