# c++ *(Type*) property name

Tags: c++, ampersand

```
void* SendMsg(void* msg) {
    char *result;
    char tmpBuf[1000]={0};
    message send_msg =*(message*)msg;//?
```

The problem is * and (*)type.

*(message*)"parameterName";

"message" is custom made struct.
I know "parameterName*" is pointer, receives address.  but "*(parameter)" phrase gets value from address.  How I should call this?

Comment: Leave a space between `=` and `*` in memoriam for the pre-historic C operators =*, =+, etcetera.

Comment: I would say `declare a new variable called send_msg of type message and initialize it with msg, cast to message star dereferenced`.

Comment: In data streams (file or net), data is often serialized as bytes (for which `char` was used in C). You then send the type-erased pointer (`void*`) and the length. To convert such a pointer back to the original type here, it's first cast to a pointer of that type `message*` and then dereferenced, using the `*`-operator.

Comment: `(message*)msg` is a cast from type `void*` to type `message*` (pointer to message). Then: `*` is access operator - it gives you the access to the value pointed by a pointer. Take a look also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061332/c-asterisks-ampersand-and-star)

Comment: so this is equalto "*message (parameter) " Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The code is in C-style whwere a void pointer is passed to the function. To use it it is cast in C-style to message* and immediately dereferenced (in this case assigned to a local variable named send_msg).

This code in C++ is technically known as a red herring for possible issues.

In C++, I would expect a base-class (interface) as parameter or a template parameter.

Comment: so ,  this is same meaning to "*message Parameter".  Am I right?

Comment: Yes, if the parameter was passed as `message* param`, then `message send_msg = *param;` would be the same. Of course, with the code in the question things could go wrong if `void*` doesn't really point to a "message" struct.

Answer (score 1):

`(message*)msg` says "pretend that `msg` is a pointer to an object of type `message`. `message send_msg = *(message*)msg;` says "pretend that `msg` is a pointer to an object of type `message` and copy the `message` object that it points at into `send_msg`. That will work fine if `msg` in fact points at an object of type `message`.